# Will stl container free memory after deleting heap based object?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am fairly new to C++, so I have got this question:
I am know that stl containers do not deallocate memory from heap pointers, one need to deallocate it himself, and I know that containers call destructors of objects being deleted, but say we have this abstract code:

```
Object* pObject = new Object();
vector<Object>[i] = *pObject;
```

Now after vector gets destroyed will it actually free memory pObject pointing to? Or it will just call the destructor of Object, making it invalid and leaving the memory marked as "occupied" for memory manager?

Thank you.

Comment: How could it? The container doesn't actually contain the pointer, but a *copy* of the object pointed to by `pObject`.

Comment: You're not posting code that could be compiled, but assuming you mean something like `vector<Object> v; ...populate at least i+1 elements...; v[i] = *pObject;` then the value of `pObject` at the time of the assignment will be copied into the `vector` at index `[i]`, the `vector` then owns the copy of the value but not the object still addressed by `pObject`, which the user code must still `delete`.

Comment: If you use `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` it will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually placing `pObject` in the `std::vector`, you're placing a copy of what `pObject` points to.  Therefore the object in the `std::vector` and `*pObject` will be totally distinct.

When the `std::vector` is destroyed, it will call the destructor of this copy of the object, but your original object will be unaffected.  I.e. `pObject` will still point to a valid object, and will have to be `delete`'d separately.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `vector<Object>` hence, a `vector` of `Object` not `Object*`. The `new` is not needed at all in this case.

Standard containers will manage the memory they allocate, not yours. If you have a container of pointers to objects you have `new`ed, then you will need to `delete` them before the container goes out of scope.

If you want the container (with some allies) to manage the memory for you, use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`. There are `boost` and `tr1` equivalents if you compiler does not yet support C++11.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> container;
```

The container will manage the smart pointers, and the smart pointers in turn manage the memory.